# Insert digital signature into existing pdf file

Tags: ruby, pdf, digital-signature

I need to insert a digital signature into already existing pdf files, using a rails application server. (Basically, clients upload pdf files and the server signs them with a local certificate)

I've been using JSignpdf to insert digital signatures into pdf files, and started probing for gems for ruby...

I've found another portable file to do this job on rubypdf site http://soft.rubypdf.com/software/pdf-digital-signe, but cannot find any gem or even example code to do this in ruby.

I've looked also at [Digital signature verification with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999096/digital-signature-verification-with-openssl), but couldn't understand how to actually sign an already existing document, with a local certificate file.

I also took a peak at http://code.google.com/p/origami-pdf/ , but this seems a bit harsh for a supposingly "simple" (at least in concept) task.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: The task is only "supposingly" simple, yet has many caveats and complexities on all levels. That's one of reasons why you can't find anything - I doubt one would invest significant effort into developing an industrial-quality PDF signer for Ruby. I'd suggest a couple of good components for .NET/Mono if you can call external classes in some way.

Comment: Hey @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp, i guess SOGETI did it with Origami, and now I've put it here, after exploring the realms of Origami and OpenSSL for a bit. Enjoy.

Comment: @MrWater: could you please provide some sample code showing how you can use jSignPDF to add digital signatures to your PDF using Java?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some research, recurring to the [OpenSSL documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) and exploring the [Origami solution](http://code.google.com/p/origami-pdf/), i built the code below, and managed to insert a locally generated signature/certificate into a pdf document. Now I just need to figure out how to use this with an external generated certificate (check version 2 below, where i solved it). I've opened a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162975/openssl-not-enough-data) where you can find some details on a difficulty i had with OpenSSL and [DER encoded](https://support.ssl.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19) certificates.

To develop version 2, i also spent some time wondering how to add an annotation - so the signature becomes visible in Adobe reader - without adding a new page to the document. From [origami documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/origami/1.2.3/Origami/PDF#append_page-instance_method), i found the get_page method, which solved my last problem on this. I'm using Adobe Reader X, for the record.

Hope you find this useful as I will ;-).

**VERSION 1 - Generate certificate and key file, and insert them directly into the document**

```
require 'openssl'

begin
  require 'origami'
rescue LoadError
  ORIGAMIDIR = "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\origami-1.2.4\lib"
  $: << ORIGAMIDIR
  require 'origami'
end
include Origami

# Code below is based on documentation available on
# http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048

open 'private_key.pem', 'w' do |io| io.write key.to_pem end
open 'public_key.pem', 'w' do |io| io.write key.public_key.to_pem end

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new 'AES-128-CBC'
pass_phrase = 'Origami rocks'

key_secure = key.export cipher, pass_phrase

open 'private_key.pem', 'w' do |io|
  io.write key_secure
end

#Create the certificate

name = OpenSSL::X509::Name.parse 'CN=nobody/DC=example'

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
cert.version = 2
cert.serial = 0
cert.not_before = Time.now
cert.not_after = Time.now + 3600

cert.public_key = key.public_key
cert.subject = name


OUTPUTFILE = "test.pdf"

contents = ContentStream.new.setFilter(:FlateDecode)
contents.write OUTPUTFILE,
  :x => 350, :y => 750, :rendering => Text::Rendering::STROKE, :size => 30

pdf = PDF.read('Sample.pdf')


# Open certificate files

#sigannot = Annotation::Widget::Signature.new
#sigannot.Rect = Rectangle[:llx => 89.0, :lly => 386.0, :urx => 190.0, :ury => 353.0]

#page.add_annot(sigannot)

# Sign the PDF with the specified keys
pdf.sign(cert, key, 
  :method => 'adbe.pkcs7.sha1',
  #:annotation => sigannot, 
  :location => "Portugal", 
  :contact => "myemail@email.tt", 
  :reason => "Proof of Concept"
)

# Save the resulting file
pdf.save(OUTPUTFILE)
```

**VERSION 2 - Use existing certificates to sign a pdf document**

```
require 'openssl'

begin
  require 'origami'
rescue LoadError
  ORIGAMIDIR = "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\origami-1.2.4\lib"
  $: << ORIGAMIDIR
  require 'origami'
end
include Origami

INPUTFILE = "Sample.pdf"
@inputfile = String.new(INPUTFILE)
OUTPUTFILE = @inputfile.insert(INPUTFILE.rindex("."),"_signed")
CERTFILE = "certificate.pem"
RSAKEYFILE = "private_key.pem"
passphrase = "your passphrase"

key4pem=File.read RSAKEYFILE

key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new key4pem, passphrase
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read CERTFILE)

pdf = PDF.read(INPUTFILE)
page = pdf.get_page(1)

# Add signature annotation (so it becomes visibles in pdf document)

sigannot = Annotation::Widget::Signature.new
sigannot.Rect = Rectangle[:llx => 89.0, :lly => 386.0, :urx => 190.0, :ury => 353.0]

page.add_annot(sigannot)

# Sign the PDF with the specified keys
pdf.sign(cert, key, 
  :method => 'adbe.pkcs7.sha1',
  :annotation => sigannot, 
  :location => "Portugal", 
  :contact => "myemail@email.tt", 
  :reason => "Proof of Concept"
)

# Save the resulting file
pdf.save(OUTPUTFILE)
```

Comment: I have similar requirements but I am using Java. I think jSignPDF or jPDFSecure should do. I'd like to know which library you have used to add digital signature/certificate to PDF?

Comment: @MrWater this gives me `method_missing': No method `add_annot' for Origami::Page (NoMethodError). do you have a hint what could be the reason for the error?

Comment: @tarekahf only now I saw this. If I recall (this was in 2012) I was using Jsignpdf app, not lib, so cannot answer you directly. Maybe you ought to try and check how to use the command line with  'java -jar JSignPdf.jar --help' as stated in http://jsignpdf.sourceforge.net/ and maybe someway call the command line from your app ?

Comment: @ManuKaracho not really, and I haven't look into this code for some years now, so cannot really remember what errors I stumbled into at the time. Have you tried to debug with printing to screen ? (logger.debug)

Comment: @ManuKaracho Change page.add_annot(sigannot) to page.add_annotation(sigannot) should fix the No method `add_annot' error.

Comment: Hey @MrWater, how did you acquire the cert in version 2? From the list of Adobe's Approved Trust List it's unclear the best way to go about this

Answer (score -2):

If you're working on a project for pay, you might want to consider [jPDFSecure](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfsecure/), a commercial Java library built for developers to digitally sign PDF documents and change security settings on PDF Documents. With jPDFSecure, your application or java applet can encrypt PDF documents, set permissions and passwords, and create and apply digital signatures.  jPDFSecure is optimized for performance and is built on top of Qoppa's proprietary PDF technology so there is no need for any third party software or drivers.

jPDFSecure has a simple interface to load PDF documents from files, network drives,URLs and even input streams, which can be generated runtime or come directly from a database. After changing security settings, jPDFSecure can save the document to a file, a java.io.OutputStream or a javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream when running in a Java EE application server to output the file directly to a browser.

jPDFSecure is platform independent and can be used in any environment that supports Java, including Windows, Mac OSX and Linux.

Comment: And how would i integrate this with ruby ? Why would jPDFSecure would be any better than jSignpdf ?

Comment: Probably an advertising bot