# OpenSSL not enough data

Tags: ruby, openssl, digital-signature, x509

I've generated a self signed certificate using Adobe X, and exported a pfx file (for my private key) along with a .cer file (for the certificate).

I then try to collect the certificate, along with the key, but for some reason, OpenSSL is giving the error

```
OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError: not enough data
```

Here is my code

```
require 'openssl'

CERTFILE = "test.cer"
RSAKEYFILE = "test.pfx"

# Open certificate files

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read CERTFILE)
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read RSAKEYFILE )
```

My certificate was generated using Adobe X reader, and is a self-signed certificate. It is working fine to sign pdf documents...

What might i do to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently OpenSSL has some problems reading directly from .cer files, and for the key, we should use only the private_key, and the pfx has both the privatekey and the cert.

So, i installed openSsl locally, and first [converted](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html) my .cer certificate to .pem with the following command :

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl x509 -inform der -in "c:\mydir\test.cer" -out "C:\mydir\certificate.pem"
```

and then extracted my privatekey from the pfx file (based on [this](http://sycure.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/tips-using-openssl-to-extract-private-key-pem-file-from-pfx-personal-information-exchange/) site) :

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl pkcs12 -in "c:\mydir\test.pfx" -nocerts -out "c:\mydir\test_pk.pem"
```

just make sure you have your pfx pwd and select a passphrase when you extract the privatekey.

Here is the final code :

```
require 'openssl'

CERTFILE = "certificate.pem"
RSAKEYFILE = "test_pk.pem"
passphrase = "your chosen passphrase for the private key"
key4pem=File.read RSAKEYFILE

# Open certificate files

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read CERTFILE)
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new key4pem, passphrase
```

And voilá :-), we have successfully mapped into memory both our certificate and privatekey, and can put it to uses like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078006/insert-digital-signature-into-existing-pdf-file)

Answer (score 2):

While trying to create an [OpenSSL::X509::Certificate](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html) object from '.cer', I found this error:

```
OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError (not enough data)
```

I checked that file was actually a `DER-encoded certificate` which is in binary format. In that case, we should read the file contents by **File.binread**.

To check if the file is PEM or DER encoded? We can use the following code:

```
require "open3"
require "openssl"

def pem_cert?(file)
  details, status = Open3.capture2e("file", file)
  return false unless status.success?
  details.rpartition(":").last.strip == "PEM certificate"
end

contents = if pem_cert?(cer_file_path)
    File.read(cer_file_path)
  else
    File.binread(cer_file_path)
  end

OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(contents)
```

This is a pure ruby way, without any shell interaction.