# How to send arguments into Paperclip processor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments, paperclip, processor

i'm trying to understand how to send a model value into a Paperclip custom processor, and just can't figure out why it is so difficult, or what the solution might be, since i'm trying to solve this for some days now...
Here is my code, extracted from both my model and processor.

From my model :

```
...
  has_attached_file :receipt_file,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :path => "/:style/:id/:filename",
                    :s3_protocol => "https",
                    :styles => { :text => { style: :original, receipt_id: self.id }},
                    processors: [:LearnProcessor]
...
```

Why can't I use the "self.id" to get the receipt Id ? 
How is it that `"/:style/:id/:filename"` gets translated into something like `/original/1/abc.pdf`, and if I put `receipt_id: :id`, all i get from `options[:receipt_id]` (see below) is `:id` instead of `1` ?

Will I need some kind of Interpolation ?

Processor Code

```
module Paperclip

    class LearnProcessor < Processor
      attr_accessor :receipt_id,:style


      def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
        @file           = file
        @current_format = File.extname(@file.path)
        @basename       = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
        @style = options[:style]
        @receipt_id = options[:receipt_id]
        puts "Options #{options.inspect}"
      end
...
```

Comment: Why don't you save the attachment in an instance variable as done in the gem?

Comment: By the way, url is actually built within the interpolation process

Comment: @apneadiving, what do you mean by "saving the attachment in an instance variable"? Where and how should i save it? Where in the gem is it being saved?

Comment: See: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/processor.rb#L26

Comment: This was definetely a head start and i am now using attachment.path. It seems though that my id isn't on the path, although i do send it as an argument... Do you know how i can print the incoming variables in the processor to the log file ? (logger, log and puts don't seem to be working)

Comment: I've just managed to debug with Rails.logger.debug, but just to see that the id isn't there...I get `original//filename.pdf`

Comment: What's your exact expected result?

Comment: i expected to have original/1/filename.pdf where "1" is the receipt_id.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a Paperclip specific issue, but there is a Ruby issue that I can address. Ruby allows you to call class methods in your class definitions which provide intuitive DSLs like this one here:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :receipt_file
end
```

The problem is that you are expecting to reference the model's `id` when you are calling this class method, but the `id` is only available on instances of the class. So this will not work. Usually this sort of thing is done using a block that is evaluated at runtime, once an instance is available.

```
has_attached_file :receipt_file,
                    # ...
                    :styles => { :text => { style: :original, receipt_id: lambda{self.id} }},
```

However, Paperclip needs to know how to accept and call the block and I'm not sure if it does. There's probably a different way to achieve what you are trying to do, and I'm not sure what that is, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in an initializer:

```
module Paperclip
  module Interpolations
    def receipt_id attachment = nil, style_name = nil
      #you should handle the case when attachment and style_name are actually nil
      attachment.instance.receipt_id
    end
  end
end
```

Then you could have a path like:

```
:path => "/:style/:receipt_id/:filename",
```

Comment: I don't understand...why would i need "receipt_id" in the path? My model is already Receipt, and i have the path `:path => "/:style/:id/:filename"`...My instance doesn't have a receipt_id...

Comment: I noticed that id is already interpolated in interpolations.rb

`def id attachment, style_name
      attachment.instance.id
    end`
So why isn't it filled when i invoke attachment.path on my processor ?

Comment: Yes `id` is already in the interpolator so your path should be ok. What do you need in your processor?

Comment: well, i've code to insert a digital signature into a pdf file (check the version 2 of that code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078006/insert-digital-signature-into-existing-pdf-file, and would like to do this in my processor. for this, i basically want to store the file to a temp dir, where a new file gets generated with the signature on it, and then upload it to the server. Ideally, i would even do this asynchronously, with delay_paperclip.

Comment: Perhaps i am not thinking this right? I've managed to add the digital signature to the file, but now, i only cannot send the file to the right destination. I get a `Receipt file No handler found for <AWS::S3::S3Object:mybucket/original//Sample_signed.pdf>` error, but the file is being uploaded to an empty name folter inside the original folder